# Can't get angular/material to start working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've installed with the command:

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

I added to **app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
```

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

I tried in my **test.component.html** to test out

```
<button mat-button>Click me!</button>
```

I get an error in the console like this:

```
bidi.es5.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (bidi.es5.js:86)
    at eval (bidi.es5.js:88)
    at Object../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/bidi.es5.js (vendor.bundle.js:39)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (core.es5.js:60)
    at Object../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js (vendor.bundle.js:255)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
    at eval (autocomplete.es5.js:17)
    at Object../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js (vendor.bundle.js:191)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
```

**ng -v** gives me this:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.0) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same Angular version as to what Angular Material v6 uses: Angular v6

See https://update.angular.io for info on how to update your dependencies.

Alternatively, consider installing `5.x.x` of Angular Material.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the module inside your test component? You need to import

```
import {MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';

       imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule]
```

inside each component.

I think its mentioned somewhere in the documentations, that you shouldn't import it into the app.module or create a global module for it.